display 2 images simultaneously with button response jspysch
I am trying to display two different images simultaneously with a set duration and a button response. I currently have them appearing sequentially but cannot seem to figure out how to have them appear simultaneously.
var trial = { 

    timeline: 
    { 
    type:  jsPsychHtmlKeyboardResponse, 
    choices:  "NO_KEYS", 
    trial_duration: 3000, 
    response_ends_trial: false, 
    stimulus: 'Get ready to begin', 
    },

  {
    type: jsPsychImageKeyboardResponse,
    choices: "NO_KEYS",
   trial_duration: 5000,
   response_ends_trial: false,
    stimulus: jsPsych.timelineVariable('pract1')
 }, 
  

  {
    type: (resp_mode == 'button' ? jsPsychImageButtonResponse : jsPsychImageKeyboardResponse),
    choices: (resp_mode == 'button' ? ['Yes','No'] : ['Y','N']),
    trial_duration: 5000, 
    response_ends_trial: true,
    stimulus: jsPsych.timelineVariable('pract2') 
  },
],
timeline_variables: [
  { pract1: 'pract/gprac.png', pract2: 'pract/gprac.png'} 
]
}

